# angular 2 template use console.log

Tags: angular

I would like to use the console.log inside the inline template but can't find any directions.

```
@Component({
  selector:"main",
  providers: [ItemService],
  template:`
    <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{console.log(item)}} <----- ??? 
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
     </li>
    </ul>

  `
})
export class HomeComponent {
  private items: Array<ItemModel>;

  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `console.log` doesn't return anything, so you're binding `undefined` into your HTML. What are you actually trying to achieve? If you want to see the details of each item for debugging purposes, consider putting `{{ item | json }}` in your template instead, or just iterate over the list and `log` it within the class wherever you get access to it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would like just to check the item and then delete the console.log(item)

Comment: But what does *"check the item"* actually *mean*? If you just want to see its content, use the JSON pipe as I and Günter have suggested. If not, please clarify what you *do* want - why do you want it in the console, particularly?

Comment: Guenter solution did the trick, didn't know about the JSON pipe as I just started with angular2.

Comment: OK, cool. In the future, please note that this kind of thing is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - you didn't want to use console.log particularly, you just wanted to see the content of the objects you were iterating over.

Comment: Being that this is an XY problem, I really think we should edit the title and text to better match problem X. Though I found this question exclusively by searching for Y, so I think it should still be left in, just better identified as  not the problem.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can't access globals, statics, ...

You can only access properties of the component the view belongs to.

You can add a

```ts
log(val) { console.log(val); }
```

to your component and use it like

```ts
{{log(item)}}
```

but be prepared this to be logged quite often (every time change detection runs).

For debugging I prefer

```ts
 {{item | json}}
```

Answer (score 45):

> Better way to do it :
>
> This way you can access all the console properties on template side

---

> Component side :

```
export class AppComponent  {
  console = console;
}
```

> Template Side :

```
{{ console.log('----------------> Logging') }}
{{ console.warn('----------------> Warning') }}
{{ console.error('----------------> error') }}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-console-log-template)**

Answer (score 12):

an easy way to debug is to create a pipe for that :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'log'
})
export class LogPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        console.log(value);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you just have to write this in the template :

```
{{ variable | log }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple and working solution, if you want to print each *item* in the console, without creating any additional method in the .ts file

1. Add in .ts file *console*

```ts
export class AppComponent  {
    console = console;
}
```

2. Add in .html file c*onsole.log*

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ console.log('-', item) }} 
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
</li>
```