# ERROR TypeError: _co.setInterval is not a function

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I am using Angular 5. I am trying to create a GameComponent having a start button. When Start button is clicked, it should periodically call startGame(), which increments a number and log it to console. Here is the code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
 <app-game-control></app-game-control>
</div>
```

game-control.component.html

```
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="setInterval(startGame(), 1000);">Start</button>
</p>
```

game-control.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.css']
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {
  cnt: number = 0;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  startGame() {
    this.cnt = this.cnt + 1;
    console.log ('Count is ' + this.cnt);
   // alert('Hello');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because you can't access the global functions within the template directly.

You can use it like in **template side** :

```
(click)="setIntrvl()"
```

**Component side** :

```
setIntrvl(){
   setInterval(() => this.startGame(),1000);
}
```

---

> **And if you still want to use on template side , you can [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607363/angular-2-template-use-console-log/47089027#47089027) it like**

**Component Side :**

```
cnt = 0;
setInterval = setInterval;

startGame() {
    this.cnt = this.cnt + 1;
    console.log ('Count is ' + this.cnt);
}
```

**Template Side :**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="setInterval(startGame.bind(this), 1000);">Start</button>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setinterval-templateside)** (With both demo Template side + Component Side)

Comment: `setInterval(this.startGame(), 1000);` wouldn't behave as intended, though. It should be `setInterval(this.startGame, 1000);`

Comment: Error is gone and incrementing but logging 'Count is NaN'. Is there anything with with specifying cnt: number ?

Comment: @SilverFish , you can checkout the both method in working condition here , https://angular-setinterval-templateside.stackblitz.io , please check.

Comment: @SilverFish , Glad to know that demo helped you , will you please upvote and accept the answer then ?